# Deserialize an array of objects with Gson

Tags: java, json

I know how to deserialize normal JSON object with "Gson" library but I am facing problem to deserialize an JSON array with several JSON object and arrays. I am trying to get the time in the `arrival_time` JSON object in this simple below but I don't know how to structure my class to accomplish that. Can someone explain me how to do that?

**Simple:**

```
[{"route": 1,
  "info": [
            {"direction": "Surrey Quays"},
            {"stops": [{"stops_name": " Tenison Way"},
                       {"arrival_time":{
                                          "mon-fri": [ "05:38", "06:07","06:37"],
                                                "sat": ["05:34","06:01","06:31"],
                                                "son": ["06:02","06:34","07:04"]
                                        }

                       }
                      ]
            }
          ] 

}]
```

Comment: how's your target type looks like?

Comment: Nested JSON requires nested objects so `JsonArray info = ...`

Comment: Could you paste code for your target object? Also, run your json through jsonlint.com. You are missing a comma in your payload.

Comment: What do you mean with target type? it looks as in the JSON simple above. It is JSON array.

Comment: @Derek_M: I have added the missing comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse this Json using following structure:

```
class ArrivalTime {
    public List<String> mon_fri;
    public List<String> sat;
    public List<String> son;
}

class Stop {
    public String stop_name;
    public ArrivalTime arrival_time;
}

class Info {
    public String direction;
    public List<Stop> stops;
}

class RouteInfo {
    public Integer route;
    public List<Info> info;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
RouteInfo[] routes = gson.fromJson(/* your json string*/, RouteInfo[].class);
```

Arrival times will be available at something like this (it is ugly but I just want you to present the sample structure for this json string):

```
System.out.println(routes[0].info.get(1).stops.get(1).arrival_time.sat.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

To learn the structure you could use a javascript object or a online builder.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/